# NaN results with pandas mean function

Tags: python, pandas

I try to have the mean of a row in my Python DataFrame, but I get a NaN return for every row.
Why I get this result and how can I solve that ?

Goog key ratios :
http://www.gogofile.com/Default.aspx?p=sc&ID=635118193040317500_6234

```
path = 'GOOG Key Ratios.csv'
#print(open(path).read())
data = pd.read_csv(path, skiprows = 2, names = ['Y0','Y1','Y2','Y3','Y4','Y5','Y6','Y7','Y8','Y9','Y10'], index_col = 0)
noTTM = data.iloc[:,0:10]
print(data.mean(1))
grossMargin = noTTM[2:3]
print(grossMargin.mean(1))
```

Return:

```
Gross Margin %   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Regards,

Comment: If you have `nan` in your output then that usually means there was only `nan` in the input, modulo a bug.

Comment: How can I check If my input is NaN ? Because when I print the grossMargin I got numerical value..

Comment: By calling `pandas.isnull` on any object. E.g., you can call `pandas.isnull(the_frame)`.

Comment: Another way you could get NaN in the output is if the data types aren't what you think they are, so the math operations aren't working.  Are you sure they're numbers and not strings?

Comment: Well I got a non-null return. Strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you have a bunch of `nan` values is because you don't have homogeneous column types. So, for example when you try to average across the columns it doesn't make sense because `pandas.read_csv` will only convert into a numeric column if it makes sense, e.g., you don't have string dates or other text in the same column as numbers.

I recommend also that you do a simple `df.head()` to check your data before doing even simple analyses. It will save you a lot of time in the future when you're wondering why your output is "weird".

That said, you can do the following to convert things to numeric values, but this isn't necessarily guaranteed to make sense:

```
In [35]: df = read_csv('GOOG Key Ratios.csv', skiprows=2, index_col=0, names=['Y%d' % i for i in range(11)])

In [36]: df.head() # not homogeneously typed columns
Out[36]:
                               Y0       Y1       Y2       Y3       Y4  \
NaN                       2003-12  2004-12  2005-12  2006-12  2007-12
Revenue USD Mil             1,466    3,189    6,139   10,605   16,594
Gross Margin %               57.3     54.3     58.1     60.2     59.9
Operating Income USD Mil      342      640    2,017    3,550    5,084
Operating Margin %           23.4     20.1     32.9     33.5     30.6

                               Y5       Y6       Y7       Y8       Y9     Y10
NaN                       2008-12  2009-12  2010-12  2011-12  2012-12     TTM
Revenue USD Mil            21,796   23,651   29,321   37,905   50,175  55,797
Gross Margin %               60.4     62.6     64.5     65.2     58.9    56.7
Operating Income USD Mil    6,632    8,312   10,381   11,742   12,760  12,734
Operating Margin %           30.4     35.1     35.4     31.0     25.4    22.8

In [37]: df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).head()
Out[37]:
                             Y0     Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4    Y5    Y6    Y7    Y8    Y9   Y10
NaN                         NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Revenue USD Mil             NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Gross Margin %             57.3   54.3  58.1  60.2  59.9  60.4  62.6  64.5  65.2  58.9  56.7
Operating Income USD Mil  342.0  640.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
Operating Margin %         23.4   20.1  32.9  33.5  30.6  30.4  35.1  35.4  31.0  25.4  22.8
```

Comment: data.replace(',','',regex = True) to replace , with nothing and easy to tranform into float type with the gentleman method !

Comment: Glad you like the `replace` method!